# Add "order" to a scope defined in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

In my Test.rb model I have a scope like this:

```
#....
has_many fathers
scope :msr, includes(fathers: :kids)
```

the `kids` table/model its self let's say has a column named `finger`

and in the controller I am using my query like this:

```
 @tests = Test.msr.where(organization_id: params[:id]).limit(3)
```

I want to add a "order" clause so I can sort by the number of fingers each kid has.
But not sure where and how can I add that "order" clause?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? order by registry patient_counts first then measure off targets?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
scope :ordered_by_kid_fingers, order('kids.fingers DESC')
```

this is assuming that you load the associations through `joins` or `includes` so

```
>> Test.joins(fathers: :kids).ordered_by_kid_fingers
```

should work

UPDATE: defining both in scope

```
scope :msr, includes(fathers: :kids).order('kids.fingers DESC')
```

Comment: well I want to have both the "includes" part and also the "order" part to be defined in the scope.

Comment: hmm, weird...
once I add the order, the json returns NOTHING.... once I take out the order, JSON return correctly.

Comment: yup that is weird. but we're going to have issues working out what the problem is if we're not actually looking at the exact code :)